# List append method within a function not working

Tags: python, list, append

I have a table of data in a txt file.
I bring it into Python with:

```
a1_file=open(file_path,'r')
```

then I go to the second line to skip the headers:

```
a1_file.readline()
line_string=a1_file.readline()
```

Being a comma separated function I want to obtain a list where the position of the first 5 commas is stored. To this purspose I am trying to use this function:

```
def commas_in_line(table_row):
    commas=[]
    while len(commas) <5:
        if len(commas)==0:
            i=0
        else:
            i=commas[-1]+1
        k=table_row.find(',',i)
        commas=commas.append(k)
    return commas
```

I call the function with:

```
commas_in_line(line_string)
```

The code reports this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#52>", line 1, in <module>
    commas_in_line(line_string)
  File "C:/1WritingPrograms.py", line 11, in commas_in_line
    while len(commas) <5:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

with

```
>>> line_string
'30/04/2020,30,4,2020,122,0,Afghanistan,AF,AFG,37172386,Asia\n'
```

I tried substituting in the function:

```
commas=commas.append(k)
```

with:

```
commas=commas+[k]
```

and it works, but how can I use the `append` method? Why does it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially `.append()` does not return the new array. `.append()` is sort of like an inplace function, where the value is appended into the array. So you do not have to return anything. When you say `commas=commas.append(k)`, a new entity is returned, which is NoneType. Please just leave it as `commas.append(k)`

Comment: It's not "sort of like an inplace function" ***is*** one,

Answer (score 0):

You add values to a python list with:

`commas.append(k)`

You use the `=` operator to define a list, not to alter one. For instance, for

```
commas = ['a', 'b', 'c']
commas.append('d')
```

`commas` will now be (a, b, c, d).

There is more about python lists here https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp